# Give example of applications in maths domains or more generally of the use of Borel measure that is not a Radon measure

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures

I'm looking for examples of research domains or themes ,where Borel measure that are not Radon measures are used in some ways.

Comment: measurable cardinals, the Dieudonné measure on $\omega_1$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a trivial example, but consider the counting measure defined over the Borel sigma algebra. As it is a measure defined over the Borel sigma algebra, it is a Borel measure. It is not a Radon measure, as it is not finite on all compact sets.

Evidently, it has many applications. For example in statistics, where it is used to construct empirical measures.

Answer (score 1):

Geometric measure theory, and all fields where you have to work with Hausdorff measures. Indeed, let $s \in [0,\infty)$ and $\mathcal{H}^s$ denote the $s-$dimensional Hausdorff measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\mathcal{H}^s$ is a Borel regular outer measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, but it is not a Radon outer measure unless $s\ge n$.

Note that, as an example, with Borel regularity of a measure you can apply lots of theory: for example the approximation of outer measures by open and closed sets. The Radon measure allows you to approximate outer measures also with compact sets, instead of closed sets.